# CiviVolunteer fail: extension resource url is not configured correctly

Tags: civivolunteer

I am working on Joomla 3.6.5
CiviCRM 4.7.14

I just did a fresh install of CiviVolunteer 4.6-2.2.1

The install seems to have worked (no errors reported). But when I try to use this feature by going to

```
Events>Manage Events>Configure>Volunteer
```

I get this error:

"Your extension resource url is not configured correctly. CiviVolunteer cannot work without this setting.
Correct the problem at Settings - Resource URLs."

So I go to Settings - Resource URLs, and this is my setting for custom extensions > Extension Resource URL:

```
/public_html/media/civicrm/custom_ext/
```

It matches what I have under Settings - Upload Directories > Extensions Directory:

```
/public_html/media/civicrm/custom_ext/
```

I have other extensions installed and working properly from the same directory, such as SparkPost, Public Autocomplete, etc.

So I suspect this is an .htaccess issue.  I checked with my host, and they say the file

```
/public_html/media/civicrm/.htaccess
```

is blocking access:  The .htaccess file reads:

```
<Files "*">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

My host says this file is being generated by CiviCRM, not by them.  My other CiviCRM extensions are working fine.  So what am I missing?  Do I modify the .htaccess file?  Or would that create a security nightmare?  Or is this an issue that doesn't involve .htaccess at all?

Comment: Is that exactly what you see in the fields for resource URL and extensions directory? They should either have the full URL or path, or have token in [square brackets] in front of them.

Comment: What I see exactly in those fields is "/home/uscucedd/public_html/media/civicrm/custom_ext/".

Comment: I am on WordPress 4.8.1 / CiviCRM 4.7.23 and am seeing the same issue.  In CiviVolunteer, the absolute URL works - no error message; the relative URL does not - error message comes up and CiviVolunteer new project page is empty.